# How to move ubuntu from usb to computer

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

So I accidentally followed the wrong process and installed ubuntu onto bootable usb instead of my pc. here were my steps.

1. Incompetently attempted to install with unetbootin on sda3 and recieved a ext4 file system creation in partition failed error
2. Used rufus on usb and added iso to try again
3. Plugged in usb and instaled on "erase disk" option thinking it would wipe my pc and install ubuntu on my computer
4. Now pc only boots with usb due to sda3 ext4 failure and ubuntu is entirely on my usb instead of my pc

I want to wipe my pc completely and only have ubuntu but I still have the option to boot with unetbootin so I assume that it erased data off usb instead of my computer.

Comment: The installed system could be migrated to a different storage device...by somebody experienced in chrooting. It's not easy. Your installed Ubuntu system does not itself have an Ubuntu installer. So go back to your .iso, re-make your install USB, and do the familiar install again.

Answer (score 0):

The [step-by-step](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) from Canonical is really good at going through the process and letting you know what each option does.

Hope you have better success this time